# Spark executor Input column within Application UI

Tags: apache-spark

Within the Spark Application UI at port 4040, If I click on Executors, I see an 'Input' column. What does this column mean? My Spark job is running very slow. Even with a small test dataset (100KB), this value is very large (24MB). Wonder if this is pointing to the issue. Any help appreciated!

Thanks!
Ashish

Comment: what do you see in the stage input column?